# get object name returned in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have a code like this:

```
var object = {
property_1:'value_1'
}

var arr = [object]
```

I want to be able to get an object name returned as a string. So it would look something like this:

```
arr[0].name     /*return 'object'*/
```

or

```
arr[0].property_1.objectName     /*return 'object'*/
```

This obviously isn't a valid code, but is there any that could actually do this?

Comment: This isn't possible. Objects don't know what variables refer to them.

Comment: @Clonkex He doesn't want a property name, he wants the variable name.

Comment: `'object'` isn't the name of the object. It's just a variable that happens to have the object as its value. Many variables can have the same value, which one is its "name"?

Comment: @Barmar Oh true, I was too hasty with my flag. Not sure if I can retract it. Oh wait yeah I can, retracted.

Comment: @Barmar The name has no meaning. I used .name as a theoretical built in property that returns the object name to make clear what I wanted.

Comment: Objects don't have names.

Comment: You have a basic misunderstanding of how variables work in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do what you want. However, you could do the following:

```
var objects = {
    object1: {
        property_1:'value_1'
    },
    object2: {
        property_1:'value_2'
    }
};

// Use this to get an array with the names
function getNames() {
    return Object.keys(objects);
}

// Use this to get the properties of an object by it's given name
function getProps(name) {
    return objects[name];
}
```

Execution example:

```
var names = getNames();

for(i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var name = names[i];
    var values = getProps(name);
    console.log(name);
    console.log(values);
    console.log(values.property_1);
}
```

Output:

```
object1
{property_1: "value_1"}
value_1
object2
{property_1: "value_2"}
value_2
```

All this considering you are using ES5.
With ES6 you could simply do the following to get a list of object names and properties:

```
Object.keys(objects).map(key => ({name: key, properties: objects[key]}))
```

I hope this helps you in some way!

Answer (score 0):

**is there any that could actually do this?**

No. `var object` is not what you are assigning to the array, the content of it is what you assigned.

```
var object = {
    property_1:'value_1'
}

var arr = [object]
```

Is the same as:

```
var object1 = {
    property_1:'value_1'
}
var object2 = object1;
arr = [object2];
```

and in the second example object1, object2 and arr[0] all point to the same object, and that object has no name.